# Delete some parts from a log file

Tags: text-processing

I want to delete part of a column(7th column:/user1/index...),it's defined by space. This is an example of my log file

```
192.xx.xxx - - [07/Apr/2017:14:21:15 +0200] "POST /user1/index.php?m=xxxxx&doajax=do_ajax_request&action=xxxx HTTP/1.1" ...
192.xx.x.xx - - [07/Apr/2017:14:21:15 +0200] "GET /user2/index.php?m=xxxxx&doajax=do_ajax_request&action=xxxxx HTTP/1.1"....
```

I want just to delete all the users that's means user1 and user2 too because I just want analyse the request doesn't matter the users 
Like that

```
192.xx.xxx - - [07/Apr/2017:14:21:15 +0200] "POST /index.php?m=xxxxx&doajax=do_ajax_request&action=xxxx HTTP/1.1" ...
192.xx.x.xx - - [07/Apr/2017:14:21:15 +0200] "POST /index.php?m=xxxxx&doajax=do_ajax_request&action=xxxxx HTTP/1.1"....
```

I tried to use this command just for to extract the request(/index.php?m=xxxx)
 cat /var/log/test.log| {print $7}'| awk -F/ '{print $3}' 
but I dont know how to replace  this request on the 7th column where I can find my request 
Thanks

Comment: this is trivial to do with sed or similar tools... suggest to go through https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/sed/info , give it a shot and update if you are stuck

Comment: @Sundeep http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing would probably be a better choice. That said, the devil's in the details. Sara, please [edit] your question and explain what will be the same in all lines and what will change. Do you only want to remove the specific string `/user1`? Or can it be `/user2` as well?

Comment: @terdon I want to delete all  the users just this part I tried to use cat /var/log/test.log| {print $7}'| awk -F/ '{print $3}' but I dont know how to replace this text  on the column 7 where I can find my request

Comment: Sara, please [edit] your question to add extra data, comments are easy to miss, hard to read and can be deleted without warning. You mentioned the 7th column. How are columns defined? Spaces? Tabs? Something else? Please [edit] and explain exactly what you need to do. How can we know what part of each line to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's,POST /[^/]*/,POST /,'  logfile | awk ...
```

or in the awk script if you use the default field separator (FS)

```
sub ("POST /[^/]*/", "POST /", $7) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's work, just but can I filter if my request is sent by POST or GET? I need to do two times this command, for some request that are POST and others that are GET?

Comment: You can pipe two `sed` commands like `sed 's,...' logfile | sed 's,...' | awk ...`  or use two `e` sed arguments `sed -e 's,...' -e s,...' logfile | awk ...`  or use two `sub` functions in your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below sed option.

```
sed -i 's:/[a-zA-Z0-9]*/:/:2' logfile
```

Here, it is looking for a pattern that starts with '/' and has alphabets and number(for username) and ends with '/' is replaced with just '/' for each line in the file.

Or

```
sed -i 's: /[a-zA-Z0-9]*/:/:2' logfile
```

Here the only difference from the first command is that, it also takes the space before the first /user* in the line.

Comment: 1) since you use `:` as separator, why escape `/` ? 2) won't this replace month name (e.g. `Apr`) as it appear first in the line ?

Comment: @Archemar - Absolutely correct. I had not noticed the month name in the file. Thanks very much for your inputs- I have updated my answer